# How to set the superuser bit?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have a backup script that contains several "sudo" commands. I don't want to have to type my username and password each time I run this script. So, I tried to add the "SUID" bit like this:

```
sudo chmod u+s <filename>
```

Now my file looks like this:

```
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root erelsgl 1868 Nov 12 09:03 <filename>
```

But, when I run the file, I still get a password prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ownership of your file is: user=root group=erelsgl.

User **root** belongs to **root** group.

So to fix your problem:

```
   chown root:root <filename>
   chmod u+s <filename>
```

After that you can remove sudo directive in your  script.

I tested this on lubuntu 12.04.

Another better approach to this kind of problem is configure sudoers. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496204/specify-password-for-sudo-in-script/497238#497238) is an example.