# Specify password for sudo in script

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

I am making a script that will update my system (and do some other things, but that doesn't matter). I want the script to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --yes` automatically. I use --yes so I won't have to choose yes when it runs; it upgrades all packages automatically without me having to do anything. That said, I want to put my password in the script somehow so I won't have to type in my password when I run it either, probably with an argument or something. You know, something I can put at the end like `sudo apt-get update --passwd MYPASSWORDHERE`. I have tried that and it doesn't work, but that's an example of what I want. What argument (--passwd or --password or something) do I put at the end to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable automatic updates?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates)

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/307067/how-to-execute-sudo-commands-with-expect-send-commands-in-bash-script

Comment: This is a duplicate and there are several options open to you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with updating my system; I just want to know how to have the password put in automatically when using sudo in a script.

Comment: I meant about you saying it was a duplicate in your first comment; not your second comment. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo doesn't behave that way, for security reasons. You can echo the password to sudo using the -s option, but I don't suggest it. Even if you protect your script from other users, they can still see your parameters using e.g. `ps -ef`.

I think your problem is better solved by installing the [unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) package.

Answer (score 5):

If your script runs as "yourUser", you could create a simple file:

```
  sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myOverrides
```

with this directive:

```
  yourUser ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-get
```

You can find an useful explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password).